# Split an array and use that to reference another table and sum another related field

Tags: vba, ms-access, split, onclick, ms-access-2010

In Access, I have an array of division numbers from a MultiSelect list that is in a text box as an comma delimited array. I would like to split the array. Once split, I'd like you use the division numbers to reference a division table and add number of stores related to each division. The table has Division 1, Number of Stores 10, Division 2, Number of Stores 20

I've tried to split the array and I don't know where to go from there.

```vb
Private Sub Stores_Impacted_Click()

    Dim TextString As String
    Dim Result() As String
    TextString = Me!mySelections.Value
    Result = Split(TextString, " ")
    Dim item As Variant
    For Each item In Result
  
    Next item
End Sub
```

Comment: "reference a division table and add number of stores related to each division" isn't really specific enough for anyone to make useful suggestions without having to guess exactly what you want to do.

Comment: I have a field that has an array of divisions, (1,2,3,4), Then I have a table that has Division 1, Number of Stores 10, Division 2, Number of Stores 20, etc.  I split the array of divisions and look for the number of stores attached to each divsion selected and sum the total number of stores

Comment: Are your "division numbers" actually numeric, or text?  You could run something like "select Sum(d.numOfStores) from divisions d where d.divisionNumber in (" & Replace(TextString, " ", ",") & ")"

Comment: divisions numbers are text and my id/primary key, Number of stores is numeric.  also, this is for a button on an Access form.  So on click, it will add the sum to a text box.

Comment: Is the list comma-separated?  In your code you're splitting on space.   You should be able to put Gustav's suggested code inside your loop and then sum the results from that `DCount`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DCount` and a single code line:

```vb
    For Each item In Result
        Debug.Print DCount("*", "DivisionTable", "Division = '" & item & "'")
    Next item
```